# Using OpenLayers 3 in IE8 (canvas issues)?

Tags: javascript, canvas, internet-explorer-8, openlayers-3

Does OpenLayers 3 support IE8? I've implemented a map on one of my sites but when I checked it in IE8 on XP then I get an error which traces back to `canvas.getContext("2d")` on line 27951 of ol-debug.js. It seems that IE8 does not support the canvas element, so should I be doing something different to set up my map or will it just not work on IE8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenLayers 3 has a define ol.LEGACY_IE_SUPPORT which you will need to set to true in a custom build to support IE < 9. Then you will need to use the DOM renderer but this won't support vector layers. More info on custom builds can be found here: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/tree/master/tasks